# Can I use the Touch ID on an iPhone to unlock Ubuntu?

Tags: login, password, iphone

I have my iPhone next to me - and it's quicker to touch my finger to the Touch ID than type my password.

Can I unlock my computer with my fingerprint via my iPhone?

Comment: I don't have Iphone, so I can't really look in to it much but perhaps you can adapt this to your needs http://pedroassuncao.com/lock-and-unlock-ubuntu-using-your-iphone